# How to minimize input exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code, which gets the job done just fine, but as you can see it is very lengthy and can be confusing :

```
private void addRecord() {
    String firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("First Name: ");
    if (firstName.length() <= 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is not a valid input.","Input error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        addRecord();
    }//end if

    String lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Last Name: ");
    if (lastName.length() <= 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is not a valid input.","Input error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        addRecord();
    }//end if

    String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Student Number: ");
    int studentNumber = Integer.parseInt(a);
    if (a.length() <= 0 || studentNumber == 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is not a valid input.","Input error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        sortMenu();
    }//end if

    String major = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Major: ");
    if (major.length() <= 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is not a valid input.","Input error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        addRecord();
    }//end if

    String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("GPA: ");
    double gpa = Double.parseDouble(b);
    if (b.length() <= 0 || gpa > 4.0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is not a valid input.","Input error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        sortMenu();
    }//end if

    tree.addNode(studentNumber, firstName, lastName, major, gpa);
}//end addRecord
```

Is there a better way that I can write this to check each input without having to have that if statement per each one? I would like to minimize this as much as possible.

Comment: Considering all the if statements are different, I don't see a way personally, if they were common you could have extended and overridden the JOptionPane method.

edit* I also just noticed that if any errors occur with input you restart the process completely, as a user this would annoy me greatly

Comment: Hmm gotcha.. is there a way I can include all of those prompts in the same dialog box? Instead of having to show a box for each prompt

Comment: You could create your own box with 4 fields and action listeners

Comment: I would extract a method here

Comment: Yeah i realized that it starts completely, I actually just copied each statement for each case and still have some editing to do so that will change, thanks tho @EyeOfTheHawks!

Comment: There are a couple other things I would do to reduce coupling, but it's just style and consistency changes.  Your method is called addRecord(), but it adds a record as well as reads input.  Just a thought.  No sense in nitpicking at this point, best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void checkString(String st, boolean or) {
    if (st.length() <= 0 || or){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is not a valid input.","Input error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        addRecord();
    }
}
private void addRecord() {
    String firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("First Name: ");
    checkString(firstName, false);

    String lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Last Name: ");
    checkString(lastName, false);

    String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Student Number: ");
    int studentNumber = Integer.parseInt(a);
    checkString(a, studentNumber == 0);

    String major = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Major: ");
    checkString(major, false);

    String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("GPA: ");
    double gpa = Double.parseDouble(b);
    checkString(b, gpa > 4.0);

    tree.addNode(studentNumber, firstName, lastName, major, gpa);
}
```

The `or` parameter is included for the extra condition.

Comment: Something doesn't look like.  If the first name is fine, but the last name isn't, aren't you going to ask for the first name again?  The stack could get very large if you keep having errors.

Comment: @JustinKSU see my comment in the question section, I realize that it will still be going back to the very beginning regardless of what input is incorrect. It's not finished yet and that is certainly something that will be changed. Thanks tho :)

Comment: I don't think it will work because it will return back to the addRecord() method.  It will end up something like this (First Last(fail), First, Last, Number, Major GPA, (continuing first execution) Number, Major, GPA.